# Microsoft CRM 2011 cross domain authentication

Tags: windows-authentication, dynamics-crm-2011

We are creating a separate web site whose contents will mashup with a Microsoft CRM installation through various iframes.  Our plan is to utilize Integrated Windows Authentication with our web site and pass credentials to an OrganizationServiceProxy to access CRM.  However, for IFD (Internet Facing Deployment) we aren't clear on how this would work.

In CRM 2011 how do you map a user that authenticates through IFD to a proper active directory user that can be used to authenticate into the CRM service endpoint?

Any sample/pseudo code would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamics CRM 2011 relies on Claims-Based-Authentication when using IFD. At the backend it uses ADFS 2.0.

If you want to achieve Single-Sign-On for your website then take a look at how to [Implement Single Sign-on from an ASPX Web Page or IFRAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509061.aspx). This article also mentions the [Walkthrough: Single Sign-on from a Custom Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509057.aspx).

Basically, your website has to trust the same STS as Dynamics CRM.